# Firebase saving objects with maps

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I do not know why but I can not save my Object to FirebaseDatabase.
Can someone help me?

My object:

```
public class ChatEntity {

    public static final String ENTITY_IDENTIFIER = "chats";

    private String id;
    private String chatTitle;
    private Map<String, ProfileEntity> users;
    private Map<String, ProfileEntity> administratorsUser;
    private Bitmap chatIcon;

    ... Getters and Setters ...

}
```

I'm saving this with:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(ChatEntity.ENTITY_IDENTIFIER).child(chat.getId()).setValue(chat);
```

And only this is saved:

```
{
  "1521122180142&Teste&tduWYxVHRVPVIx6Sv4p8fNwKKJi2" : {
    "chatTitle" : "Teste",
    "id" : "1521122180142&Teste&tduWYxVHRVPVIx6Sv4p8fNwKKJi2"
  }
}
```

The field `chatIcon` was `null`, so it's ok. But the two Maps has 1 and 2 entrys, and don't getting saved.

How can I save it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might see, the Firebase database only takes the `String` objects that you try to save. Any other object is not guaranteed to be saved, specially the `Bitmap` one. If you want to save a `Bitmap`:

- Use Firebase Storage
- Get the **Base64** `String` from the `Bitmap`.

To save the nested `HashMap`, you might want to call the database several times (one for each `Map`), or to convert the Maps' values into Strings with a `/` for each time you are editing a child (although both of them are very messy).

Comment: So if I create a method that return a JSON string of that object, I can save that. But how can I restore it from database?

Comment: You just need to cast the `dataSnapshot.getValue()` to the object you want, always checking that it's compatible.

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write), the `Bitmap` is not a supported data type in Firebase Realtime database. Remember, as a general rule, I'd say, never use base64. You don't really need to base64-encode your image. If you want to store images, don't use Firebase Realtime database, use [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/).

In order to have your database populated with `users` and `administratorsUser`, change the type from those maps with `ProfileEntity` objects. If you want to use maps, you can use to set/update them directly on a `DatabaseReference` object.